# Why is this scss output is not showing the calculated total but a string of the var instead?

Tags: sass

I have this .scss file / sass:

```
$var-1:100px;
$var-2:100px;
$var-3:100px;
$total-height:$var-1 + $var-2 + $var-3;
.some-class{
  max-height: calc(100vh - $total-height); // 100vh + 300px 
}
```

The final outputted css just outputs the following:

```
.some-class{
  max-height: calc(100vh - $total-height);
}
```

The var does not get processed, so I was wondering why the `$total-height` isn't outputting the expected `300px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [interpolate](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) the variable to use it in `calc()`:

```
.some-class {
  max-height: calc(100vh - #{$total-height});
}
```